# Where can I find a good Delphi or Object Pascal implementation for a circular buffer

Tags: freepascal, circular-buffer, delphi

My main purpose is to have a generic data buffer that I can use for transfers.

I'm thinking of something along the lines of what XCopy did.

Is there something already made out there or a good example one can follow?

Answer (score 4):

The [Tomes of Delphi by Julian Bucknall](http://www.boyet.com/FixedArticles/DADSBook.html) describes code for circular buffers, the code of which is freely available as a download. I haven't got the book to hand at the moment, so I can't tell you exactly where to look (though I think it might have had something to do with carrying out data compression with a sliding window).

Comment: The sources that you mean can be downloaded here: http://www.boyet.com/Code/ToDADS_source.zip. It looks like you can get the book for $28 here: http://www.lulu.com/content/435417

Comment: I should add that the book is worth every cent/penny.